# Status of 5GHz support for 802.11 WiFi devs in BSD (2014)

Tags: freebsd, wifi, openbsd

To put it simply, 2.4GHz band doesn't work anymore due to the plethora of various Wi-Fi and other devices, whereas 5GHz is still almost entirely empty.

Do any of the BSDs -- FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFly -- support wireless networking in the 5GHz band?

Any one of 802.11a, 802.11n, 802.11ac, as long as it's on the 5GHz band?

Answer (score 1):

For FreeBSD: ath(4) suport 802.11a;  802.11n should be available for ath(4) in FreeBSD 10.

AFAIK nothing available for 802.11ac

There is also a Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers#Driver_capabilities_2

Comment: hm, i guess i was under a wrong impression that 802.11a is not supported; i guess that's not correct -- looks like FreeBSD and OpenBSD both support at least 802.11a.

Comment: 802.11n 5GHz work in FreeBSD 10 (with some limitations, e. g. no firmware for radar detection/avoidance). 802.11ac is not supported for now.